# c_str() of an rvalue - unsafe?

Tags: c++

Could anyone explain why the following crashes with an access violation at `0xFFFFFFFF` at `avformat_open_input`?

```
std::string u8(const std::wstring& str)
{
    return boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(str);
}

AVFormatContext* open_input(const std::wstring& filename)
{
    AVFormatContext* context = nullptr;
    avformat_open_input(&context, u8(filename).c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    avformat_find_stream_info(context, nullptr);
    return context;
}
```

while the following works:

```
AVFormatContext* open_input(const std::wstring& filename)
{
    auto u8filename = u8(filename);
    AVFormatContext* context = nullptr;
    avformat_open_input(&context, u8filename.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);        
    avformat_find_stream_info(context, nullptr);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Show us avformat_open_input definition.

Comment: @Tomek: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavformat/utils.c;h=2f926bb4e0784b031456fce7b477a7eebac8b440;hb=refs/heads/master#l583

Comment: What does the implementation of `u8` look like?

Comment: I think you also need to provide the compiler/boost version and maybe the generated assembly for two dummy calls that exhibit the problem (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `u8(filename).c_str()` should be usable until `avformat_open_input` returns. It's probably saving the pointer you give it and then using that during `avformat_find_stream_info`.

Post the docs for these avformat functions, or their implementations so we can see if it's actually doing that.

---

It doesn't look like `avformat_open_input` is doing anything wrong. Now I suspect that there's undefined behavior occurring somewhere earlier in the program. Try using a tool like valgrind or static analysis and see if that turns up anything.

Comment: bames53: See second comment under question.

Comment: If this were so then the AV would not occur at `avformat_open_input`, rather in the call to `avformat_find_stream_info`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah, you're right. And the code appears to copy the string anyway.

Comment: Accepted. It's undefined somewhere earlier.